# Create a dataframe from a dictionary which is inside a tuple which is inside a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my final line of code , I need to create a python dataframe from the below line of code. This code is outputting the following see screenshot ,  How will I create a pandas dataframe from the below code ?

```
from pprint import pprint
query="Pepper"
results=search(query, top_k=2, index=index, model=model)
cutoff_list = []
number_list = []
print("\n")
for result in results:
    #print('\t',result)
    cutoff_list.append(result)
 
cutoff_list
```

[Screenshotstrong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADa1I.jpg)

I need the following output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iquvV.jpg)

Please help

Comment: Please do not post images. Try to copy'n'past your code into a code block. This makes it much easier to try a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = []

for item in cutoff_list:
    tmp = {}
    for item2 in item:
        tmp.update(item2)
    data.append(tmp)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Since [`append()` is depricated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) a solution with `pd.concat()` is preferable.